# vue transition-group item with flex/grid wrapper moves to top-left

Tags: vuejs2, flexbox, transition, css-grid

I have this:

```
<transition-group
    name="product-list"
    tag="section"
    class="product-list"
    @before-leave="beforeLeave"
>
    <product
        v-for="watch in watches"
        :key="watch.id"
        :item="watch"
    >
    </product>
</transition-group>
```

and as it says in the docs:

```
.product-list-enter-active,
.product-list-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.product-list-enter,
.product-list-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
.product-list-leave-active {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Issue**: when any element is leaving (it is removed from the list) **it goes top-left** because of the position absolute... which kinda breaks the aesthetics of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this solutions:

```
<transition-group
    @before-leave="beforeLeave">
    ...
</transition>
```

```
methods: {
    beforeLeave(el) {
        const {marginLeft, marginTop, width, height} = window.getComputedStyle(el)

        el.style.left = `${el.offsetLeft - parseFloat(marginLeft, 10)}px`
        el.style.top = `${el.offsetTop - parseFloat(marginTop, 10)}px`
        el.style.width = width
        el.style.height = height
    }
}
```

thanks to [docmars](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/transition-group-leave-transition-w-position-absolute-jumping-to-top-left-flip/12258/4) in forum.vuejs.org

If there is a **better solution** out there please let me know